# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object on show.blade.php

Tags: laravel, web, controller

CompaniesController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Company;
class CompaniesController extends Controller
 {
 public function index(){ 
    $companies=Company::all();

      return view('Companies.index',['companies'=> $companies]);
}

public function create()
{
    //
}
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}


public function show(Company $company)
    {
     $company=Company::find($company->company_id);
 return view('companies.show',['company'=> $company]);
} 

public function edit(Company $company)
{
    $company=Company::find($company->company_id);
      return view('companies.edit',['company'=> $company]);

   }

  public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
    {    
      $companyUpdate=Company::where('company_id',$company->company_id)->
             update([
            'name'=> $request->input('name'),
            'description'=> $request->input('description')
]);

   if($companyUpdate){
return redirect()->route('companies.show', ['company'=> $company->company_id])
-> with('success','Company updated successfully');
}
     return back()->withInput();

}


public function destroy(Company $company)
{
    $company=Company::find($company->company_id);
  if($company->delete()){
  return redirect()->route('companies.index')->with('success','Company    deleted successfully');
    }

  return back()->withInput()->with('error','Company could not be deleted');
}
 }
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
 @section('content')<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 pull-right">

   <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> {{$company->name}}</h1>
    <p class="lead">{{$company->description}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Get started today</a></p>


  </div>
   {{--  @foreach ($company->projects as $project)
    <h2> {{$project->name}}

    </h2>

    @endforeach --}}  



  <div class="row" style="background:red;margin:10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
      <p class="text-danger">  Information present </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
    </div>

    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-left">

      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Actions</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="/companies/{{ $company -> company_id }}/edit">edit</a></li>
          <li>



          <li>


          <a   
          href="#"
              onclick=" var result = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Company?');
                  if( result ){
                          event.preventDefault();
                          document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
                  }
                      "
                      >
              Delete
          </a>

           <form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('companies.destroy',[$company->company_id]) }}" 
            method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </form>


          </li>
          <li><a href="#">add new</a></li> 
        </ol>
      </div> 
    </div>


@endsection
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/companies', 'CompaniesController@index');

 Route::get('/companies/{company_id}', 'CompaniesController@show');
```

I am trying to display the page with url companies/12 using these 2 routes in laravel the error displayed is

"Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\pmanager\resources\views\Companies\show.blade.php)"

and when i try 
Route::get('/companies', 'CompaniesController'); 
everything works eventhough i haven't assigned a route for show.can someone please help me and say why does this happen?

Comment: please add your `controller code` where you use for view file

Comment: can you dump $company and $project variable in you view ? You can use `dd()` method for that

Comment: This error occurs because your collection has not given property

Comment: USE : `dd($company)` in your `controller@show method`

Comment: try with `<h2> {{$project['name']}} </h2>`

Comment: a white page appeared with a null value

Comment: so no record comes in `$company` check your query

Comment: my query is find since the value is working with the route

Comment: echo `$company->company_id` its have value or not

Comment: Route::get('/companies', 'CompaniesController');  This first route makes the code fine but  the second route is wrong and i cant know why                      Route::get('/companies/{company_id}', 'CompaniesController@show');

Comment: Is your primary key `company_id` or `id`...?

Comment: yeah its having a value but its not an object

Comment: its company_id..

Comment: In your route, change `{company_id}` to `{company}`. Go to your controller and `dd($company)`.

Comment: in your controller `Company Request` has not added

Comment: You are welcome. You can answer the question yourself and state the changes that worked for you.